# how do i write the validation in the model in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, php-7.2, laravel-6.2

When i validate the **phone number** i the controller then it is working but it increases the lines of code and i also have to write the callback functions, But i don't want to write the callbacks,instead i want to do it in the model, is there any way to do it??

```
'phone' =>['required',"regex:/^\(?[\d]{3}\)?[\s-]?[\d]{3}[\s-]?[\d]{4}$/",function($attribute, $value, $fail) use($id) {

                    if (strpos($value, "-") !== false) {
                        $exist = User::where([["phone", $value],["id","!=",$id]])->count();
                        if($exist){
                            $fail(ucwords($attribute).' is already taken.');
                        }else{
                            $result = User::where([["phone", str_replace("-","",$value)],["id","!=",$id]])->count();
                            ($result) ?  $fail(ucwords($attribute).' is already taken.') : "";
                        }

                    }else{
                        $exist = User::where([["phone", $value],["id","!=",$id]])->count();
                        if($exist){
                            $fail(ucwords($attribute).' is already taken.');
                        }
                    }
                },],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be able define the function in your model as a static function that returns a closure, so then you can call it to get the closure and pass it on as a callback.

```
// In the model
public static function myValidationClosure($id){
   return function($attribute, $value, $fail)use($id) {
     if (strpos($value, "-") !== false) {
         $exist = User::where([["phone", $value],["id","!=",$id]])->count();
         if($exist){
             $fail(ucwords($attribute).' is already taken.');
         }else{
             $result = User::where([["phone", str_replace("-","",$value)],["id","!=",$id]])->count();
             ($result) ?  $fail(ucwords($attribute).' is already taken.') : "";
         }
     }else{
         $exist = User::where([["phone", $value],["id","!=",$id]])->count();
         if($exist){
             $fail(ucwords($attribute).' is already taken.');
         }
     }
   };
 }
```

Then you can use it in the validation as

```
'phone' =>['required',"regex:/^\(?[\d]{3}\)?[\s-]?[\d]{3}[\s-]?[\d]{4}$/", MyModelClass::myValidationClosure($id)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Always The Good Solution is For The Validation is Make a Custom Request which is seperate and easy to handle follow this =>

`php artisan make:request CustomRequest`

The Request:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use App\User;

class CustomRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [

            'phone'        => [
                                    'required',

                                    'min:10', 
                                    'max':10',             
                                    'regex:/^\(?[\d]{3}\)?[\s-]?[\d]{3}[\s-]?[\d]{4}$/',     

                                 ],

        ];
    }
}
```

It will provide you a default validation message but if you want to make a custom message the you can do by making `message()`

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation

Hope It will help you!

Comment: Thanks, i get that , but is there any way to not write callback that i am using because as you suggested it will only validate the regex, but it will not validate if the number exists in the db or not as in callback. Thanks again.